# How can I get only computers on LAN based on IP address range?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ping, lan

I am writing a C# Winforms program to get all the computers that are connected to my LAN, based on the given IP address range.

I am using the `Ping` class to identify the computers.
But the problem here is I am getting responses from all the devices like (printer, IP phone, etc) that are connected to LAN.

Please help me in filtering these devices and to get only computers from LAN.

Comment: There's no real way of telling without resorting to other things such as SNMP and AD on Windows and they're not 100%. NMAP also for example tries to do some finger printing.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? What do you want to do once you've found all the computers on the network? Are you bothered about the operating system they are running?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible to tell using PING whether a network node is a computer/printer/ip phone etc.

You would need to use a higher level protocol like NETBIOS or DNS to work this out but it depends very much on how the devices are implemented.

Comment: i am using DNS to get the host name but i am not sure about how to differentiate devices using Dns.

Comment: I'm not sure either :) it would depend on whether the naming convention used reflected the type of device.

Answer (score 0):

Well, chances are that the printer, phone, etc. have general purpose computers in them running a TCP/IP stack and some specialized server software, so it boils down to what your definition of what a "computer" is... still, it sounds like more trouble than it's worth, unless you can identify something that only what you think of as computers will have, and that all of them will have. On a Windows network, SMB, perhaps - but that could catch a NAS that exposes storage over SMB.

I don't think there's a general way to do what you want to do. Like Lloyd pointed out, nmap does some fingerprinting, but that is far from perfect (it will usually get pretty close to a specific OS version, but it can't tell what kind of physical device is running that OS).

Comment: So is there a alternative way to find out? I ve tried with netapi32, but it requires domain name to be specified, since i want to list all the systems irrespective of domain/workgroup i cant use this. I cannot use active directory services since i dont have required credentials.